# como abrir uma nova janela de um arquivo diferente com tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu tenho o arquivo *main.py* e quero abrir uma nova janela clicando em um botão chamando o *arquivo janela2*, eu consigo fazer apenas chamando o `import janela2` em uma função, mas o botão só funciona uma vez.

```python
from tkinter import *

root =  Tk()

class funcoes():
    
   def janela(self):
       import janela2 

class application(funcoes):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        self.tela()
        self.frames_da_tela()
        self.widgets_frame()
        root.mainloop()
    
    def tela(self):
        self.root.title('Main')
        self.root.configure(background='#483D8B')
        self.root.geometry('800x600')
        self.root.resizable(True, True)
        self.root.minsize(width=600, height=480)
    
    def frames_da_tela(self):
        self.frame_1 = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame_1.place(relx= 0.25, rely= 0.25, relwidth= 0.50, relheight= 0.46)
    
    def widgets_frame(self):
        self.bt_dentista = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar 1', command=self.janela2)
        self.bt_dentista.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)
        
        self.bt_paciente = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar 2', command=self.janela3)
        self.bt_paciente.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.34, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)
        
        self.bt_consulta = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar 3')
        self.bt_consulta.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.48, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)

        self.bt_sair = Button(self.frame_1, text='Sair')
        self.bt_sair.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.62, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)   

        self.lb_pesquisar = Label(self.frame_1, text='O que deseja fazer?')
        self.lb_pesquisar.place(relx=0.32 , rely=0.04)






application()
```

Answer (score 0):

Só consegues importar um módulo uma vez por ficheiro, ou seja, só conseguirias abrir essa nova janela uma vez. A solução para isso é bastante simples, basta passares tudo o que tens dentro do ficheiro janela2.py para uma função dentro desse mesmo ficheiro. Vamos supor que criaste uma função "novaJanela" no ficheiro janela2.py. Quando fores para chamar essa função, terás que fazer da seguinte maneira.

```
import janela2

class funcoes():
   def janela(self):
      janela2.novaJanela()
```